# R: mutate does not generate new column in self-write function

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to write a function calculating the differences between the first two columns, then take an average of them.

```
  errors = function(data, true, pred){
    library(dplyr)
    mutate(data, Error = data$pred - data$true)

    mean_err = mean(data$Error)
    return(mean_err)
  }
```

However, this function does not work as I expected. For instance, for a data source like this:

```
true = rnorm(10, 2, 20)
pred = rnorm(10, 1, 20)
dt = data.frame(cbind(true, pred))
```

This function doesn't generate a new column called "Error" and returned NA:

```
errors(dt, true, pred)
```

I was expecting the function to make the following changes to the data frame, then take an average of the errors.

```
mutate(dt, Error = pred-true)
```

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: To start `mutate` returns the modified data.frame, it doesn't change it in place. So you need to return the results of the `mutate` call inside your function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd do something like:

```
errors = function(data, true, pred) {

  require(dplyr)

  true <- enquo(true)
  pred <- enquo(pred)

  data = mutate(data, Error = !! pred - !! true)

  mean_err = mean(data$Error)

  return(mean_err)

}
```

As you're after a single value, this could also be shortened to:

```
errors = function(data, true, pred) {

  require(dplyr)

  true <- enquo(true)
  pred <- enquo(pred)

  mean_error = summarise(data, Error = mean(!! pred - !! true))

  return(mean_error)

}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you thank you. Two quick questions: 1) I see the enquo function embedded in several packages, which package does this one refer to? And why is it necessary? 2) what does "!!" do in the function?

Comment: You're welcome! It refers to the `rlang` package, but nowadays most of the helpers are included when you load `dplyr` for instance. Since `dplyr` needs unquoted function arguments (e.g. variable names), these need to be quoted (`enquo`) and unquoted (`!!`) to be recognised as part of the data frame you're referring to. Basically this allows you to play dynamically with the function: in the above example, you could have variables `right` and `preds` instead of `true` and `pred` in your data frame, and the function would still do the job in exactly the same way.